# File manager modal appearing at the bottom of publish page

Tags: control-panel

I'm getting the standard EE file upload modal showing at the bottom of the cp publish page. Any idea what might be causing it?

Many thanks
Lee

Comment: Turned out I needed Matrix 2.5.1.

Comment: Consider answering your own question and explain a bit how you came to that conclusion. It may help others in the future :)

Comment: Was it a JS conflict between the CP theme and Matrix?

Comment: Must have been a conflict of some sort, all I know is that installing Matrix 2.5.1 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I needed Matrix 2.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

9/10 times this is caused by JS errors. Check your error console to see if an add-on is breaking the CP, or something else. I see this all the time. If you find that you have errors in your console, report back and I can edit my answer for a possible culprit.