# "File Upload" box appearing at bottom of Publish Page

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager, publish-layout

I'm having an issue where the "File Upload" is appearing at the bottom of the publish page. There is quite a few JS errors in the console, but I'm unsure what files are causing this.

I though this was the same issue as:

[File manager modal appearing at the bottom of publish page](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/file-manager-modal-appearing-at-the-bottom-of-publish-page)

But they fixed it by upgrading Matrix... But I'm on the latest version! I'm running EE.29 and ALL the add-ons are up to date.

:(

[image]

Comment: Try disabling or updating the Lamplighter add-on. Looks like it might be throwing some errors.

Comment: I've seen this with an incorrect path to the /themes folder, worth checking.

Comment: Are you still having issues with this? Are you using Google Maps for EE at all? I have seen this JS error with some of my users, so if you are using Google Maps for EE, email support@objectivehtml.com and I will send you the latest code to see if it fixes it.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell Still having this issue, we only JUST installed Google Maps for EE, but this issue arrived before this add-on was installed.

Comment: Do a completely fresh upload of your EE `/themes` folder to start (excluding `third_party` of course), then log out and clear your cache. If that fails, do the same with all of your `third_party` themes.

Comment: The "undefined" error, just says it's the bottom of the site entry page? Nothing specific?!

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the themes directory of the add-on that throwing error in console.

It should work.

Comment: I would, if I knew which add-on was causing the problem!  Console isn't outputting any errors for Lamplighter and it seems to be still be there if I remove Lamplighter

Comment: ok just for check try to comment the line which is throwing error.

so we can spot the error.

Comment: or backup your current themes folder and upload a fresh theme directory of same EE version you are using  having all the latest add-ons in third party folder.

Comment: The "undefined" error, just says it's the bottom of the site entry page? Nothing specific?!